# How to use Autocomplete place function in iOS swift?

Tags: swift, google-maps, autocomplete, size

How can I implement the autocomplete place feature in iOS app. That is when I try to search something , it will give me suggestions for the places. I know about the Google autocomplete api. But the problem with that it makes the size of the app too big. We have to import the GoogleMaps pod for that and its around 100 MB. How can I use autocomplete place feature without the google maps? or make the size less then the current pod of Google map?
Code for my podfile is simple and written below

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'slotcaddy' do
# Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
use_frameworks!
pod 'Google/SignIn'

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY'] = ""
          config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED'] = "NO"
          config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = "NO"
      end
  end
end

# Pods for slotcaddy

target 'slotcaddyTests' do
  inherit! :search_paths
  # Pods for testing
end

target 'slotcaddyUITests' do
  inherit! :search_paths
  # Pods for testing
end

end
```

Anybody please help with this
TIA

Answer (score 0):

The only tutorial that I can found on the internet is by using JavaScript, although you are using IOS, then take this tutorial that I found as an additional information to you, or maybe you can get some ideas with it.

This [tutorial](https://www.igorkromin.net/index.php/2016/02/02/use-google-maps-places-auto-complete-api-without-displaying-a-map/) uses the [Google Maps Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/?hl=en) auto complete feature without having to display a map. Just check the tutorial to know the sample code that you need in your code.

Check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12024629/bind-google-places-autocomplete-on-textbox-without-instantiating-a-google-map) for more information.